# Argument 'menuController' is not a function, got undefined error on unit testing my Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm having trouble setting up my unit test project.
The first test runs, but trying to set up this one doesn't.
The message is this

```
[ng:areq] Argument 'menuController' is not a function, got undefined
```

at this line (when debugging)

```
> menuController = $controller('menuController', {
>             $scope: $scope,
>             appConfig: {}
>         });
```

This is my code under test:

```
/// <reference path="./../_references.js" />

(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module(Main.config.name)
        .controller('menuController', menuController);

    menuController.$inject = ['$state', 'appConfig'];

    function menuController($state, appConfig) {

    }

})();
```

(I removed all the code from the `function menuController`, so it would not break on that code in the controller)

And this is the testcode

```
/// <reference path="../../scripts/_references.js" /> 
'use-strict';

describe('menuController', function () {
    var menuController;
    var $scope;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module(Main.config.name);
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    menuController = $controller('menuController', {
            $scope: $scope,
            appConfig: {}
        });
    }));



    it('menuController should not be null', function () {
        expect(angular.isObject(menuController)).toBe(true);
        expect(menuController).not.toBe(null);
        expect(menuController).not.toBeUndefined();
    });

});
```

I have another controller allready running, but that one has no dependencies (and no logic yet):

TEST
`homeController = $controller('homeController');`

and CONTROLLER

```
/// <reference path="./../_references.js" />


    (function () {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module(Main.config.name)
            .controller('homeController', homeController);

        function homeController() {

            /* jshint validthis:true */
            var vm = this;

            activate();

            function activate() { }
        }

    })();
```

EDIT

It makes less sense now...
I created a copy of the homeController and called it 'zoekenController'

In the 'homeController' test this line works
`homeController = $controller('homeController');`
but this gives me an error: `var t = $controller('zoekenController');`

Same controller (other name off course)

EDIT 2
I get an error in this angular code:

```
 expression = controllers.hasOwnProperty(constructor)
            ? controllers[constructor]
            : getter(locals.$scope, constructor, true) ||
                (globals ? getter($window, constructor, true) : undefined);
```

the variable `controllers` is always 'homecontroller' and also during the test of the zoekenController it is 'homecontroller'. So it can not find the zoekenController constructor in the homecontroller.
(in my other project, which does run (but I can't seem to find out why THAT one does) the `controllers` property contains all the controllers. But it's not something I do myself, registering the controllers....

EDIT 3:
is my syntax correct?
I realize that this is testcode I copied from another project, but there we had a different syntax for the controller:

```
.controller('reviewController', [
        '$scope',
        'settings',
        'reviewService',
        '_',
        function reviewControllerInit($scope,settings,reviewService,_){

            $scope.settings = settings;
            $scope.review = {
                scores : []
            };
```

Comment: I've done numerous things, and I think it comes down to the fact that the controllers under test all have this line in them `/// <reference path="./../_references.js" />`. This file is autogenerated by visual studio, and it is sorted alphabetically... So I think the references are in the wrong order.... Rearranged them and now it works. Can that be the problem???